# Not able to install cocoa pods on EL Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan

Getting the following error:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to update your system (Which will install the ruby gems)

### STEPS TO INSTALL COCOAPODS

*UPDATE SYSTEM*

```
sudo gem update --system
```

*INSTALL COCOAPODS*

**Before EL Capitan**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**After EL Capitan**

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

*SETUP POD*

```
pod setup
```

*POD INIT (GO TO YOUR PROJECT DIRECTORY)*

```
pod init
```

*OPEN AND UPDATE POD FILE*

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

*INSTALL THE PODs AS PER YOUR NEED*

```
pod install
```

### UPDATE : Cocoapods installation with Homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH

brew install ruby

brew install cocoapods

pod --version

pod install
```

Comment: This worked after spending an hour trying to figure out how to install the Google Maps SDK. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting error while run "sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods".
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository